# lag not working as expected

Tags: r

`lag` is not working as I expected

```
a<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
a
## [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
lag(a,k=1)
## [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
## attr(,"tsp")
## [1] 0 8 1
```

I thought I would get:

```
0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

or

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you think you would get such a result? There is nothing in the documentation that supports this expectation.

Comment: The documentation says it "Compute a lagged version of a time series" - I thought that is what I want in this case?

Comment: The documentation is using `ldeaths` for the example. If you type `class(ldeaths)` you will see it returns `[1] "ts"`.

Comment: It merely shifts the "time-base". The documenatation clearly says that a time series is returned. It's unclear what you want to achieve, which makes this question hard to answer.

Answer (score 10):

You should use `Lag` from the `Hmisc` package:

```
library(Hmisc)
Lag(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), shift = 1)
# [1] NA  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was in the same predicament and this worked for me. It's ridiculous that the R lag function isn't as straightforward as this one.

Answer (score 3):

`data.table::shift` is another one:

```
library(data.table)
a <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
shift(a)
#[1] NA  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

---

Another way using `base::lag` with  the `zoo` library:

```
library(zoo)
a <- zoo(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))  #convert to zoo
```

So:

```
lag(a, 1, na.pad = TRUE)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 NA
```

Or:

```
lag(a, -1, na.pad = TRUE)
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
#NA  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

You can wrap an `as.vector` around it to get rid of the indices.

Comment: Error: 'lag' is not an exported object from 'namespace:zoo'

Comment: @user189035 As mentioned in the answer there is no `zoo::lag` (so it is not an exported object from zoo). but only `base::lag`. Essentially, you use `base:lag` on a zoo object.

Comment: Technically speaking, there's no `base::lag`; it's `stats::lag`

Answer (score 3):

Actually,

I went for this in the end:

```
c(a[-1],0)
```

Does what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

`lag` expects a `ts` object so transforming a to a time series and calling `lag`on the resulting object will work as expected.

```
a <- ts(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
lag(a, k=1)
```